# get parent child in XMLTable in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, oracle11g, xmltable

I want to know if there are any way to collect the parent child tag when you are creating an XMLTable.
The XML is like this:

```
<Data>
    <Identificacion/>
    <UOFDATA>
        <CodigoDATA v="AAAASSA"/>
        <PeriodoDATA>
            <IntervaloDATA v="2013-10-14/2013-10-18"/>
            <UPDATA>
                <CodigoDATA v="AGAGGGG"/>
                <UFDATA>
                    <CodigoDATA v="AAASSCV"/>
                    <.....
```

I´m listings all the '/Data/UOFDATA/PeriodoDATA', and i want to know the UOFData (the parent child.
I try some ways, but always return null!

```
    Select intervalo, uof, uof2, uof3 from
XMLTable(
        '/Data/UOFDATA/PeriodoDATA'
        passing (select xmltype(pl_string) as xmldataselect from consultas where cdconsult = 1000)
        columns Intervalo varchar2(60) path 'IntervaloDATA/@v',
                UOF varchar2(60) path './ancestor::UOFDATA/CodigoDATA/@v',
                UOF2 xmltype path './parent::node()',
                UOF3 varchar2(60) path './../CodigoDATA/@v'
       ) tableIntervalo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does each <UOFDATA> node have more than one <PeriodoDATA> child node?

Comment: Yes, it can have many PeriodoDATA, but only one CodigoDATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just have one parent node `CodigoDATA` but many child nodes `PeriodoDATA`, I suggest you split query into 2 different ones: the first would extract the parent information `CodigoDATA`, and the second would the `PeriodoDATA` child nodes (similar to what you are doing).

Comment: I tried to do what you says, and it works!, but unfortunately does not help me because I need to parse all xml depth (starting from the innermost (UFDATA).
I have also tried to use something like this   'fn: string-join (UFDATA / CodigoDATA / @ v, "")', to go concatenating all the UF, but not serves me too.
I need to know the ancestors!, I think that in this case, is the only solution!

Comment: The XMLTable's first parameter ('/Data/UOFDATA/PeriodoDATA') determines the root for each iteration, so that's why you don't have access to `PeriodoData`'s ascending context.

Comment: Ok, thanks mcalmeida! I'll wash my brain to see if there ara another way to do! Thank you!